# Remove data from name file

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, file-rename

After restore file from windows backup, the file name have e.g. (2015_05_13 17_30_52 UTC), the date of backup. Which shell commands remove this path from file name in all subfolder?

Comment: `rename` command ?

Comment: Is that string at the beginning, or is it at the end? Please give a full filename example.

Comment: for example 'codetemplates (2015_05_13 17_30_52 UTC).xml' or '13032009011 (2015_05_13 17_30_52 UTC).mp4'. I'd like rename in ''codetemplates.xml' or '13032009011.mp4'

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
:top
set "fnm=%~n1"
if "%fnm%"=="" goto :EOF
set "fnm=%fnm:~0,-26%%~x1"
echo.ren "%1" to "%fnm%"
shift /1
goto top
```

Save this as a file called `changeIt.bat`
Call it like this:

```
changeit.bat *(201*
```

Run it in each of the affected directories.
You have to remove the `echo.` part from above or all it does is tell you how it would rename the file. Best to run it as it is first, and then you can see what it will do. It assumes there are always 26 characters to remove, which is the length of `(2015_05_13 17_30_52 UTC)`